# What suspends my laptop after 1200 seconds of idle?

Tags: suspend

I want my laptop to stay running when it is on A/C-power even when it is idle and the lid is closed.

I managed to make it not suspend immediately when the lid is closed with:

```
/etc/systemd/logind.conf:
[Login]
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
IdleAction=ignore
IdleActionSec=1min
```

But around 1200 seconds after rebooting (no login on `gdm`) it suspends to RAM.

What am I missing?

```
$ uname -a
Linux nlv 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS \n \l

$ cat /etc/systemd/sleep.conf (# comments removed for brevity)
[Sleep]
```

Comment: Did you check for hints in the logs? Especially the `suspend entry` reason?

Comment: @Fiximan I have never heard of the `suspend entry` reason before. Which logfile should I grep in?

Comment: @OleTange either `syslog` or `kern.log` should show the reason for supension in parentheses. `grep 'suspend entry' /var/log/syslog` should result in e.g.  `[...] suspend entry (deep)` for low battery.

Comment: @Fiximan Good call. It says: `systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.` So I now just need to find the place to ignore sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this file, `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`

It should have this entry in it

```
[Sleep]
AllowSuspend=no
```

Comment: Please, use proper syntax and explain why he has to look at that file

Comment: I think that file is self expalnatory.. still updated the comment.

Comment: This approach disables all forms of sleep, including user-requested (which may of course be what‘s desired). Fixing the `gdm` configuration instead prevents the automatic 20-minute sleep while still allowing the user to suspend the system.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a `gdm` daemon setting and is controlled separately from user settings.

For changing the settings use

```
sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
```

And since you have a laptop also for battery mode:

```
sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'
```

Taken from [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#GDM_auto-suspend_.28GNOME_3.28.29) on autosupend in `gdm`.

It looks like this is a result from complying with power-saving regulations as pointed out by user Simon McVittie on [gnome.org](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/22) where the issue was discussed.

**Could not test as not running `gdm`.**